# Update MYSQL Query while using existing content

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with a row called "log". I need to update that log while using the content that was already in the file.

```
mysql_query('UPDATE messages SET log=log+"123"  WHERE uid = "'.$config["user_id"].'"');
```

That one doesn't work :/ I think it's because it's a TEXT field, with INT i can normally do

```
SET row=row+1
```

I'm sure there is a clever solution for this, thanks in advance for all hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update messages set log = concat(log, "123") where...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the + operator on strings, there is a function for that in mysql and is called concat.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

You will maybe need concat_ws to add a space or newline in between :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query('UPDATE messages SET log=log+123  WHERE uid = "'.intval($config["user_id"]).'"');
```

Comment: I thought that log in not numeric :D